# ssh could not resolve host name for ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an ec2 instance but I can't access it through ssh my instance is running well but still, it throws the same error.

It runs on putty though

My error exactly was ssh: Could not resolve hostname -: No such host is known.

Comment: Please don't reference external images. You can add them inline, or if they're actually representations of text, then include the text inline.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ssh -i keypair` not `ssh - i keypair` (with extraneous space).